# How do I configure CDK to deploy to the correct region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy a simple stack to `AWS` using `CDK`. Unfortunately though when I'm running it through my GitHub actions workflow it seems to be deploying to the wrong region and I can't work out why...

The contents of my `bin\cdk.js` look like (sample account):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const cdk = require("@aws-cdk/core");
const { CdkStack } = require("../lib/cdk-stack");

const app = new cdk.App();
new CdkStack(app, "CdkStack", { account: "000000000001", region: "eu-west-1" });
```

This looks correct to my eyes following the docs. I haven't defined anything anywhere else as far as I'm aware. If I run a `cdk bootstrap` the CloudFormation is generated. The only reference to region is:

`"environment": "aws://unknown-account/unknown-region",`

Am I missing something totally obvious here? The way I've got it configured in my pipeline is simply using:

```
            - name: CDK Deploy
              env:
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
              run: |
                  npm install -g aws-cdk
                  cdk bootstrap
                  cdk deploy --require-approval never
```

Comment: What happens if you add `AWS_PROFILE: eu-west-1`  to the env section of your pipeline configuration?

Comment: @DennisTraub Hadn't thought of env variables. Just tried AWS_DEFAULT_REGION which works well. If you answer I'll accept as you put me in the right path at least

Comment: Oh, I wrote AWS_PROFILE. I meant to write AWS_REGION, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default region as an environment variable in the pipeline configuration:

```
- name: CDK Deploy
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-1
    ...
  run: |
    npm install -g aws-cdk
    cdk bootstrap
    cdk deploy --require-approval never
```